# Visual Studio MSI Installers

Tags: windows-installer, web-setup-project

I have an Web Setup Project Installer and I would like to default the site and the Application Pool that is selected during the install process. Also I would like to have the name of the product append the current version number during the build process of the installer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Visual Studio Web Setup Project is quite a simple (and not too flexible) tool. You have some options, though (assuming you are not ready to switch to using something more flexible such as WiX or a commercial installation packaging product).

### Modify the MSI After Building

One way to do what you want is to modify the MSI file after it has been built.

You can add properties such as the following:

1. Add a property named `TARGETSITE` and set it to the metabase path of the site you need to be the default. For example, `/LM/W3SVC/2`.
2. Add a property named `TARGETAPPPOOL` and set it to the name of the application pool you need to be the default. For example, `MyAppPool`.
3. You can also set the product name by editing the existing `ProductName` property.

Making changes to MSI files can be achieved manually with tools such as [InstEdit](http://www.instedit.com/) or ORCA (which is part of the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx)).

Alternatively, you can create/find MSBuild tasks to get and set properties in MSI files. This gives you a nice way to automatically make the desired changes during automated builds.

### Invoke with Commandline Arguments

More simply, you can invoke the installation from the command-line using msiexec.exe and specifying values for the `TARGETSITE` and `TARGETAPPPOOL` properties, for example:

```
msiexec /i MySetup.msi TARGETSITE=/LM/W3SVC/2 TARGETAPPPOOL=Pool2
```

You can't mess about with the `ProductName` this way, though.

Comment: You may also use the MSI API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369426(VS.85).aspx) to automate the changes as part of the build process.
You can get a nice jscript sample that uses the MSI API from here (tweak accordingly): http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2006/10/23/mailbag-how-to-set-the-noimpersonate-flag-for-a-custom-action-in-visual-studio-2005.aspx

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your response Dave and Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

Open the MSI in Orca. Go to Property, right click and right click to add Row.

Property: TARGETAPPPOOL
value: ASP.NET v4.0

You can do the same using this VBS script:

```
Dim oDatabase 'As WindowsInstaller.Database
Const msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact = 1
Dim oInstaller 'As WindowsInstaller.Installer

Dim sFilePath 'As String
sFilePath = "C:\Test\MySetup.msi"
Set oInstaller = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set oDatabase = oInstaller.OpenDatabase(sFilePath, msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact)

sql = "INSERT INTO Property (Property, Value) VALUES ('TARGETAPPPOOL', 'ASP.NET v4.0')"    
Dim oView 'As WindowsInstaller.View
Set oView = oDatabase.OpenView(sql)
oView.Execute
oView.Close

oDatabase.Commit
MsgBox ("Done!")
```